# Quantization of the Kalb-Ramond field

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory

In string theories, I have sometimes seen the condition:

$$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\Sigma_2} B_2 \in (0,1)  .$$

This is might be obvious, but I don't see why this should be. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2650) (p. 17) they say:

> The condition $\frac{1}{4\pi^2 \alpha^\prime}\int_{\Sigma_2} B_2 \in (0,1)$ comes also from the quantization of the string action, $\exp \left( \frac{i}{4\pi^2 \alpha^\prime}\int_{\Sigma_2} B_2 \right)$, as part of the string path integral. This is similar to what happens in quantum mechanics when coupling particles to a gauge field $A_\mu$.

But why should this imply that the integral of $B_2$ is restricted to $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restriction of the flux of the Kalb ramond field to the interval $[0, 1)$ is a generalization of the Aharonov-Bohm effect to stringy or surface holonomy.

The Kalb-Ramond field is a type of a higher Abelian gauge connection. Its gauge transformation has the form:
$$\delta B = d\Lambda$$
where $\Lambda$ is a one form.

In the case of the electromagnetism, the gauge potential $A$, minimally couples to a particle moving on a manifold $M$ (it is assumed that $M$ is compact):
$$ S = \frac{q}{\hbar} \int_{\Gamma} A$$
Where $\Gamma$ is a one dimensional closed submanifold of $M$. Let $D$, be a two dimensional surface having $\Gamma$ as a boundary, then by the Stokes theorem:
$$ S = \frac{q}{\hbar} \int_{D} F$$
where, $F$ is the corresponding curvature two-form: $F = dA$.

The minimal coupling has two implications:

1. When $H^2(M)$ is nonvanishing, then for any *closed* surface $D$
   $$\frac{q}{\hbar} \int_{D} F \in \mathbb{Z}$$
   This is the Dirac's quantization condition. The nontrivial field configurations are Dirac magnetic monopoles in this case.

This condition is explained very clearly by Orlando Alvarez in [enter Topological quantization and cohomology](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103943448).

2. When $H^2(M) = 0$, but $H^1(M)$  is nonvanishing, the curvature of any gauge potential will be vanishing. In this case the connection is a flat connection. The prototype of this case is the Aharonov-Bohm effect.

In the Aharonov-Bohm case $M = S^1$ and:
$$A = \frac{q \Phi}{2 \pi r \hbar} d\phi$$
By integration over S^1, the Aharonov-Bohm phase is:
$$\phi_{AB} = \frac{q \Phi}{ r \hbar}$$
Now the physics should not change if we perform a gauge transformation:
$$A\rightarrow A + d\phi$$
Please notice, that $\phi$ is not a single valued function on $S^1$, thus $d\phi$ is closed but not exact, thus we are performing a large gauge transformation on $A$.

This gauge transformation has no effect on the Aharonov-Bohm phase, since it adds $2\pi$ to the phase.

On the other hand, if we increase the flux in the solenoid  by $ \frac{2 \pi r \hbar}{q}$ we will add also exactly $2 \pi$ to the Aharonov-Bohm phase, which is the same effect as the gauge transformation. Thus the physically distinct fluxes lie in the interval:
$$\frac{q \Phi}{ 2 \pi r \hbar} \in [0, 1)$$

For a general manifold, we can take instead of $d\phi$ an integral one form $\omega_1 \in H^1(M, \mathbb{Z})$  and perform the gauge transformation:
$$A\rightarrow A + \omega_1$$

The case of the Kalb-Ramond field is analogous:

1. It couples minimally to a string:
   $$ S = \frac{1}{4 \pi^2\alpha^{\prime}} \int_{\Sigma} B$$
   which can be written as:
   $$ S = \frac{1}{4 \pi^2\alpha^{\prime}} \int_{D} H$$
   Where, $H = dB$ and $D$ is now a three dimensional surface whose boundary is $\Sigma$.
2. When $H^3(M)$ is nonvanishing, the Dirac's quantization condition implies that for a closed surface $D$:
   $$ \frac{1}{4 \pi^2\alpha^{\prime}} \int_{D} H \in \mathbb{Z}$$
   (This case is also described in detail in Alvarez's reference). The nontrivial $B$-fields in this case are types of generalized Dirac monopoles two-forms, explicitly constructed in some cases by [Nepomechie](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.31.1921) and [Teitelboim](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269386905472).
3. When $H^3(M) = 0$ and $H^2(M)$ is nonvanishing, the large gauge transformation:
   $$B\rightarrow B + \omega_2$$
   Where $\omega_2 \in H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$ does not change the stringy Aharonov-Bohm phase (or surface holonomy):
   $$ \frac{1}{4 \pi^2\alpha^{\prime}} \int_{\Sigma} B$$
   (Here $\Sigma$ is a closed two dimensional surface)
   Which implies, that the fluxes:
   $$ \frac{1}{4 \pi\alpha^{\prime}} \int_{\Sigma} B \sim \frac{1}{4 \pi\alpha^{\prime}} \int_{\Sigma} B + 2 \pi $$
   are equivalent.

This subject is discussed by [Fuchs, Nikolaus, Schweigert and Waldorf](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/thoni/Papers/ecm.pdf)
 (page 9).